# File Upload with NGINX and PHP + user authorization first

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to set up a web service where users can upload files. The only problem that I am having is that NGINX lets ANY user upload a file prior to doing any authentication of the user. I want to be able to only let authorized users upload files.

Basically I want to pass the request to upload the file to PHP and make PHP tell NGINX that this user has indeed logged in and it can now receive files from him.

I am using NGINX and PHP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/ardinusawan/Nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend/blob/master/README.md

Comment: tell me if i am wrong. you need user authentication system and only user who logged to the system can upload the file, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Nginx [auth request module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html)

Then set up your directives in Nginx something like this:

```
location /upload/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
}

location = /auth {
    proxy_pass ...
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
}
```

Now Nginx will make an internal subrequest to /auth whenever a client requests /uploads, in this example passing the client IP in the headers but you can configure it however to suit your needs.

Your PHP script receives the subrequest, does whatever authentication you want to do and returns HTTP response code of 200 if you want to allow access and 401 if you dont.

Answer (score 1):

One example: Use the $_SESSION to check if the user is logged in. 
Do you have any code snippets? Because nginx runs under cgi/fastcgi maybe php-fpm and there are maybe different setups to get attention to it.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['allowUpload']) {
    // OK
} else {
   // please login or you are not allowed to upload
}
```

Comment: How will this not require the user to send the file? I am not sure where you are going with this....

Comment: give us more input to help

Comment: I need users to upload a file but first I want to make sure the user has logged in through php.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have some missconceptions here...

`The only problem that I am having is that NGINX lets ANY user upload a file` and `make PHP tell NGINX that ...`

*NGINX* "only" serves the webpages, is the *PHP* that (from inside of your server) let users upload (or not) the files. If you (and everyone) can upload files to your server you have a sever security risk. The main point here is to restrict externals users to direct upload any file to any folder, and then, only let the users upload a file (at the folder you decided) throught a form (for instance).

A typical scenario will be:

User access to your webpage with a file upload form. They select (`input type='file'`) a valid file and then submit the form. The form sends the file to a PHP file (upload.php) and this store to your server:

> Webpage --> form --> upload.php --> server

You can do differents things, like:

- Don't let non-logged users access to your `form` (they can't upload)
- Check in the `upload.php` if the user is logged ($_SESSION). This should be always done.
- Both of them (my recomendation)

This way, there are no way that a non logged user can upload to your server, because:
 - No direct upload permission (ssh, sftp, etc.)
 - Users that want to upload a file, HAVE TO go to your form page. If they are not logged, redirect them to LOGIN.php.
 - If someone try to direct access to upload.php will be checked with $_SESSION in order to know if is logged or not.

A (very simple) example

1 - HTML form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

2 - Upload file:

```
<?php
if(!User->isLogged()){  // or $_SESSION
   return false;        //or header('Location: login.php')
}
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does help but I was already tracking all of this...the only issue is that I DO NOT want php to receive the file....I only want php to receive the request to upload the file and then it lets nginx take over....kind of like how XSendfile works..... User sends the file --> php only receives user request --> nginx takes over receiving the file and storing directly to the hard drive.

Comment: The problem is that when you say `I only want to receive the request to upload the file` this is the file. The request is the file (with the request, comes the file data). You can not separate it, PHP gets the request and the data (that NGINX has redirected to it). Why you want this `weird` behaviour by the way? It's not working for you the `standard` way?

Comment: I guess I didn't think it was that weird.... the problem with $_FILES is that the authentication happens after the file is already stored on the server. What I'm trying to do is authenticate the user before the file is stored on the server.

Comment: Once again: The NGINX should prevent users to upload ANY file without your `validation`. This is the entry point, the PHP file. If you have only one gateway to your server (the php file), then, you can prevent not logged users to upload anything.

Comment: If you don't see it clear, post your code/files and I will try to help you, but I think that the problem is about a missconception about how server uploads works, because you can prevent not authenticated users to see your upload form or whatever you are doing to upload files... and even prevent not authenticated users to upload anything...because they don't have any permissions to access to your server, unless they use your PHP file as gateway to store it.. I explain myself?

Comment: @Miguel You said you are trying to authenticate the user before file upload. If it is the case, you can always use $_SESSION variables to validate their login status. But afaik there is no way in PHP through which you can check and validate the upload without storing it in ur server at first. This can be done through, JS or jQuery, I guess.

Comment: nginx already recevied upload, next sending to php, problem is already  NGINX recevied, that why auth is more important than session in php