# Simple password protection on private next.js site

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, next.js

I am making a next.js app and I've spent hours searching for a very simple way to password protect the app. (It will be used by a small group of friends)

I have tried using Nginx's http auth on my reverse proxy, and that works but it could be annoying to have to sign in all the time as the login doesn't persist long. (Nginx's http auth seems to 'logout' or forget the authorization very quickly)

I also don't want to dive into something as complicated as [NextAuth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-auth). I don't want user signups, custom views etc, etc.

I just want people to be able to enter one password to view the site. And I would like it to persist on their browser so they wouldn't have to log in all the time with Nginx's http auth.

Is there a way to give users a cookie once they pass the http auth, and then allow them in once they have the cookie?

Can anyone suggest a fairly simple solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the Nginx `map` directive, which lets you set a variable based upon another variable.

Inside your html block somewhere but outside any server blocks you set up your map directive

```
map $cookie_trustedclient $mysite_authentication {
  default  "Your credentials please";
  secret-cookie-value off;
}
```

Whats happening here is Nginx is setting the value of the custom variable `$mysite_authentication` based upon the value of the cookie named `trustedclient`.

By default `$mysite_authentication` will be set to `Your credentials please`, unless you have a cookie named `trustedclient` with a value of `secret-cookie-value`, in which case `$mysite_authentication` will be set to `off`

Now within the location block that you have enabled basic auth you change your `auth_basic` directive to use the new variable, like this:

```
location /secretfiles {
    auth_basic $mysite_authentication;
    auth_basic_user_file .... 
    add_header Set-Cookie "trustedclient=secret-cookie-value;max-age=3153600000;path=/";
}
```

You can set the cookie here or within your website code. The result being the `auth_basic` directive gets set to `off` for people with the right cookie, or the display message for the password box for people without it.

Not super secure, but easy and good enough for most things.

Edit from your config:

```
# Map block can go here
map $cookie_trustedclient $mysite_authentication {
  default  "Your credentials please";
  secret-cookie-value off;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
 #       ssl     on; # Delete this line, obsolete directive
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cloudflare-ssl/certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/cloudflare-ssl/key.key;

        ssl_client_certificate        /etc/nginx/cloudflare-ssl/cloudflare.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name ********.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             #   auth_basic "Restricted Content"; # Now this becomes:
                auth_basic $mysite_authentication;
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                add_header Set-Cookie "trustedclient=secret-cookie-value;max-age=3153600000;path=/";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I can't quite get it working though... I am a little confused about where the 'html block' is? In my site config file I just have one `server { }` block. I put the `add_header...` line in my location block, but I can't get it working either by adding it outside the server block or making an `html { }` block. You can see my [site config file here](http://pasted.co/36a344a6)

Comment: Updated [site config file](http://pasted.co/97b15528), realized I had one other mistake but I still can't get it working. It asks for authentication again every time I close and open the browser.

Comment: Do you mean to put the map block in the [http block](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/#the-http-block) in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file?

Comment: Hmm, seems to be working actually, just not in Edge.

Comment: Edited my answer, note the change to the  `auth_basic` directive in your location block

Comment: Nothing works in Edge. Make sure the cookie is being set, you may get better results setting the cookie in your web code instead

Comment: Thanks so much for this fantastic answer. You said it's not 'super' secure... just how secure would you say it is?

Comment: Secure enough for a little project with your mates, not secure enough for a financial institution. You have SSL so the authentication headers will be sent encrypted, but anyone who finds out your cookie value can get in. The expiry time on the cookie header is ridiculous, so you might want to dial that down a bit, maybe change the cookie value now and again.

Comment: Ya, the main problem I see with it is that if I wanted to let users 'sign out' a public device I would write a function to 'delete' the cookie by expiring it. Someone with the know-how could just go in and re-adjust the expiry date of the cookie, right?

Comment: So you make your sign out function rewrite the value of the cookie at the same time as setting it to expire, or you have another cookie which you set initially and increment on each visit and only set your auth persistence cookie after x number of visits, so visits from one off public devices never get that cookie in the first place

Comment: That's my point re security though. Basic authentication is just that, basic. If you want something more sophisticated (which it seems that if possible, you don't) then you can use the Nginx `auth_request` module to pass client credentials to your back end server and Nginx will allow/deny access based upon the back end response. Then you can start minting JWT, implementing Oauth2, SSO and all that good stuff. Much more secure, but overkill if you just want to stop people seeing the data from your weather station etc. Example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957725/